# Display most recent comment in a list view

Tags: workflow, comments

I have a list that appends comments so I have a historical view. I'd like to create a view of the list that only shows the most recent comment made in the two relevant fields, Actions Taken and Next Steps. I have created a SP 2010 work flow that basically runs

```
If Current Item:Comments matches regular expresion .+
     Update item in Current Item (Latest Comments = CurrentItem:Comments)
the Update item in Current Item (Latest Comments)
```

The workflow has a manual start.

I have a create a view that displays the Latest Comments field. Nothing is showing up though.

I'm using SP2013, online and SP Designer 2013.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this walk through to solve my question

http://officepowerups.com/2013/06/25/sharepoint-show-most-recent-comment/

Comment: Thanks for adding this, i had the same question, and will implement the same solution. (helper column).  Thanks!